Adding subitems/tasks onto a work item in Azure Devops using power automate
The problem
I would like to be able to add sub items / work items to a work item in azure devops when it is created. An example of this would be a new Work item would be created for example "Add new Get Endpoint for weather API" then when this item is brought into the sprint it would already have sub task on it for Testing, Documentation, and Releasing it.
Example
Example of what I would like that I created manually
What I have so far
I have looked into Power automate I am very new to it but I can see that you can set triggers based on when a work item is created but looking through it I cant see anything related to the sub items or task (Might be due to not knowing what they are called exactly).

Do you mean that you want to link child work items automatically when the new parent work item is created? Are your child work items pre-created and fixed? For example, all new parent work items are linked to work items with id 11, 12, and 13?

Would this create them as sub tasks? I wouldn't want them as individual items in the backlog just tasks in the sprint attached to the main item? If it would make them like in the photo then yes.

Please clarify your question in detail. What exactly do you want to do in power-automate? We can create work items in power-auto and can also link one work item to another in power-automate. But I am confused what you want to do. Please give the specific steps of your expected flow.

I would like a trigger on work item created or if there is one where it is moved into a sprint (like work item 1).
this would then create a task on the work item called test(just like 11 in the photo).
I would like to duplicate the task adding step multiple times but once I can do it once I think I am okay to just copy and paste. Thank you


"I would like a trigger on work item created"- There is such trigger in power-automate. 2. "if there is one where it is moved into a sprint" - The sprint of the work item is controlled via the "Iteration" field. So that the one needed to check is actually this field. You can use work item update trigger. 3. "this would then create a task on the work item called test" - This can be done in power-automate using create work item action.



"I would like to duplicate the task adding step multiple times" - You can create multiple tasks. But how many tasks to create and the fields of each task must be determined in advance, such as name, or other fields you need. The number of the task to be created and the fields of each task need to be provided in power-automate. After the above information is confirmed, I can try to help you implement it using power-automate.


Thank you this all sounds correct. in the above how would I connect them together to make them sub tasks?

Hi @Sam Crerar, I have shared an example for you in the answer below. Please try it.

Below is an example for your reference. When a new Issue type work item is created in Azure DevOps, new tasks will be created and linked to it as child automatically.


Add a When a work item is created trigger.
Select your org name, project name and work item type.


Add Create a work item action
Click the plus button of the trigger -> Add an action.

In the Create a work item action, configure the followings:


Iteration Path: Click the Iteration Path field, you will be able to see the output list of your "When a work item is created trigger" step. Select the Iteration Path, then the created task will have the same iteration as its parent work item.

Area Path: Select the Area Path from step1's output.
Link URL: Select URL from step1's output.
Link Type: Select Hierarchy-reverse.

Then you can click the plus button of the trigger -> Add a parallel branch to add more "Create a work item action" to create more work items.

Result: when an issue is created in my org, two tasks will be created as its child automatically.



